# Export entire rapidminer repository into multiple files

Tags: export, rapidminer

I've received some experimental data in rapidminer's ExampleSets format. The data presented as a single repository with multiple 'data entries' (not sure about correct terminology). What is the easiest way to export it into more convenient format keeping folder structure and naming?

- I know how to export single file with creating a process, that consists of **Retrieve Repository**, **Write CSV**, **Write file**. Not really works for me because I have a lot of repositories/files.
- **Loop Repository** should fit, however I can't figure out how to automatically set up filename for **Write file**.
- Another option I can think of is to implement converter myself. Sources are [available](https://github.com/rapidminer), but it might be an overkill if there is an easy solution with processes.

Comment: Another confusing thing I've noticed is a message "Expected ExampleSet but received IOObject." that didn't prevented me from exporting the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started do the following.

Inside the `Loop Repository` operator connect the input directly to the output. Set the parameter `entry type` to `IOObject` and select a repository folder containing the data you want.

The output will be a collection of example sets and other objects.

From here, you can set the `filter` parameter to restrict the entries.

Inside the operator, the macros that are defined by the operator parameters are set to the name and path of the entry in the repository and you can use these with other operators to do what you want.